# Spark accessings Kinesis stream to JSON objects

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, amazon-kinesis

I am just getting started on Spark and I am currently working on an application to stream data from Kinesis. I have a producer that is putting JSON objects in the one below

```
{
   "username":"crystalhamilton",
   "name":"Mark Cooper",
   "gender":"M",
   "address":"0305 Landry Circle Apt. 698\\nChadberg, DC 56711",
   "mail":"mcdanielandrew@yahoo.com",
   "birthdate":"1973-06-02"
}
```

and then I am trying to get my Spark consumer to retrieve it so later I can parse it. 
I have set the checkpoint interval to 2 seconds following the [Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/streaming-kinesis-integration.html), and I know that every batch will be a DStream that most likely will include multiple RDDs and I am assuming that each RDD can be parsed into an individual JSON object.

Unfortunately, I am at loss on how to read the stream and break the DStream into RDDs and then parse the RDD into the JSON document. I tried to map the Dstream with a lambda using json.dumps[x] and that does not seem to work.

```
def load_json(time, x):
    try:
        return json.loads(x[1])
    except Exception:
        log.error('Mesage in DStream is not a JSON object')
        return {}

def main(sc): 
    try:
        streaming_context = StreamingContext(sc, 10)

        kinesis_stream = KinesisUtils.createStream(streaming_context,
                                            kinesisAppName=application_config['application']['name'],
                                            streamName=application_config['aws']['stream_name'],
                                            endpointUrl=application_config['aws']['endpoint_url'],
                                            regionName=application_config['aws']['region_name'],
                                            initialPositionInStream=InitialPositionInStream.LATEST,
                                            checkpointInterval=1
                                            )


        py_dict_rdd = kinesis_stream.map(lambda x:load_json)

        py_dict_rdd.pprint(lambda x: print('username: [%s]', x['username']))


        streaming_context.start()
        streaming_context.awaitTermination()
        streaming_context.stop()
   except Exception as e:
        log.error("Exception occurred in the main() function - error: [%s]", e)
```

When I run this I get an exception that says:

```
[Stage 2:>                                                          (0 + 1) / 1]20/04/09 14:52:20 ERROR JobScheduler: Error running job streaming job 1586458340000 ms.0
org.apache.spark.SparkException: An exception was raised by Python:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.5/libexec/python/pyspark/streaming/util.py", line 68, in call
    r = self.func(t, *rdds)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.5/libexec/python/pyspark/streaming/dstream.py", line 173, in takeAndPrint
    taken = rdd.take(num + 1)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'function' and 'int'

    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.python.TransformFunction.callPythonTransformFunction(PythonDStream.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.python.TransformFunction.apply(PythonDStream.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.python.PythonDStream$$anonfun$callForeachRDD$1.apply(PythonDStream.scala:179)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.python.PythonDStream$$anonfun$callForeachRDD$1.apply(PythonDStream.scala:179)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:416)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:257)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:256)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
ERROR:app.__main__:Exception occurred in the main() function - error: [An error occurred while calling o36.awaitTermination.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: An exception was raised by Python:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.5/libexec/python/pyspark/streaming/util.py", line 68, in call
    r = self.func(t, *rdds)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.5/libexec/python/pyspark/streaming/dstream.py", line 173, in takeAndPrint
    taken = rdd.take(num + 1)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'function' and 'int'

    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.python.TransformFunction.callPythonTransformFunction(PythonDStream.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.python.TransformFunction.apply(PythonDStream.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.python.PythonDStream$$anonfun$callForeachRDD$1.apply(PythonDStream.scala:179)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.python.PythonDStream$$anonfun$callForeachRDD$1.apply(PythonDStream.scala:179)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:416)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:257)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:256)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

All the examples I found deal with word counts and could not find anything similar to what I am trying to do. Thanks in advance for any help or information that may point me in the right direction.

Regards,

--MD.